# change JSON.stringify to what?

Tags: node.js, json

i can't figure out what to place in exchange of the JSON.stringify syntax in the body parameter. It is returning a SyntaxError with a code of 800A03EA

```
const request = require('request');

const username = 'myUserName';
const password = 'myPassword';
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://siteToPostTo.com/api/v1/statuses',
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        status: 'automated message to post'
    })
};

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('headers', res.headers);
    console.log('status code', res.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. Instead, add

`json: true` to your options and don't attempt any stringification. `request()` will do the magic for you.

```
const request = require('request');

const username = 'myUserName';
const password = 'myPassword';
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://siteToPostTo.com/api/v1/statuses',
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    },
    json: true,
    body: {
        status: 'automated message to post'
    }
};

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('headers', res.headers);
    console.log('status code', res.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
});
```